# forEach loop for String array

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a string array(APN) in my bean(accessed as header). I am accessing it like this

```
<c:forEach var="apn" items="${header.APN}" >
    var g = apn;
    if (g.length!=0 && g!="null"){
        if(counter == 1){
            count=0;
             $("#img0").show();
             $("#apn0").show();
             $("#rtu0").show();

        }
        if(counter == 2){
            count=1;
             $("#img0").hide();
             $("#apn0").show();
             $("#rtu0").show();
             $("#img1").show();
             $("#apn1").show();
             $("#rtu1").show();
             $("#removeimg1").show(); 

        }
        if(counter == 3){
            count=2;
             $("#img0").hide();
             $("#apn0").show();
             $("#rtu0").show();
             $("#img1").hide();
             $("#apn1").show();
             $("#rtu1").show();
             $("#removeimg1").hide();
             $("#img2").show();
             $("#apn2").show();
             $("#rtu2").show();
             $("#removeimg2").show(); 

        }
    }
</c:forEach>
```

When I keep an alert after

```
var g = apn;
```

Alert is not popped up. I have some text boxes in my UI. When I press on + icon(rendered in the form of image), another set of text boxes appear to enter multiple values. My code is not working. Can anyone help me out

Comment: Why in earth are you closing a `<c:forEach>` with an `</c:out>`? In any case, have you checked the generated JavaScript code by rightclick, *View Source*? Does that line `var g = apn;` really look right? Is `apn` really an existing JavaScript variable? You seem to be completely new to web development in general and not really realize that JSP/JSTL is merely a HTML code generator and that JS is part of the generated HTML output and therefore doesn't "run in sync" with JSP orso.

Comment: I overlooked it... I closed correctly in my code. when I View Source it, I couldn't see that line. So my assignment is wrong?

Comment: Apparently `${header.APN}` contained nothing?

Comment: APN is a String array in my bean "header" and contains values. When they are fetched into the JS variable 'g', it is returning empty.

Comment: You said that you don't see `var g = apn;` line. But you seem to actually do see it. So, here's the question once again, is that line `var g = apn;` really right? Wouldn't you rather expect that JSP/JSTL has generated `var g = 'somevalue';` instead, which is valid JS? Fix your JSP/JSTL/EL code accordingly so that it generates exactly that JS code!

Comment: I am not sure if the assignment "var g = apn;" is right. Thats where I need help

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need an `}` just before `/c:out`. I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, i just noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignation part is incorrect. Try this -

```
var g = ${apn};
```

Comment: What is coming in alert(g);

Comment: alert itself is not coming